# Iterate over a list of floats- python

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, graph-theory

I'm trying to use Markov clustering (MCL) to cluster (6) data points, the matrix represents a similarity matrix between data points based on some criteria.

my data:

```
import warnings
import math
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
import scipy.spatial.distance as distance
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
%matplotlib inline
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
import markov_clustering as mc
import networkx as nx
import random

data = np.array([
    [0.13, 0.19, 0.21, 0.13, 0.23, 0.05, 0.05],
    [0.06, 0.06, 0.06, 0.15, 0.5, 0.05, 0.12],
    [0.12, 0.29, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.11, 0.14],
    [0.02, 0.13, 0.18, 0.14, 0.09, 0.05, 0.39],
    [0.49, 0.06, 0.02, 0.13, 0.1, 0.09, 0.11],
    [0.11, 0.18, 0.35, 0.14, 0.09, 0.07, 0.06]])

Matrix =np.array([[0, 0.0784, 0.032768, 0.097216, 0.131008, 0.025792],
       [0.0784  , 0, 0.142144, 0.16768 , 0.223104, 0.174848],
       [0.032768, 0.142144, 0, 0.069312, 0.126656, 0.053056],
       [0.097216, 0.16768 , 0.069312, 0, 0.212224, 0.095232],
       [0.131008, 0.223104, 0.126656, 0.212224, 0, 0.173312],
       [0.025792, 0.174848, 0.053056, 0.095232, 0.173312, 0]])
```

Then I run the following code of the MCL algorithm on the matrix and retrieve the clusters.

```
def addSelfLoop(Matrix):
    size = len(Matrix)
    for i in range(size):
        Matrix[i][i] = 1
    return Matrix

def createTransition(Matrix):
    size = len(Matrix)
    Transition = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for j in range(size):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(size):
            sum += Matrix[i][j]
        for i in range(size):
            Transition[i][j] = round(Matrix[i][j]/sum, 2)
    return Transition

def expand(Transition):
    size = len(Transition)
    Expansion = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            sum = 0
            for k in range(size):
                sum += Transition[i][k] * Transition[k][j]
            Expansion[i][j] = round(sum,2)
    return Expansion

def inflate(Expansion, power):
    size = len(Expansion)
    Inflation = [[0 for i in range(size)] for j in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            Inflation[i][j] = math.pow(Expansion[i][j],power)

    for j in range(size):
        sum = 0
        for i in range(size):
            sum += Inflation[i][j]
        for i in range(size):
            Inflation[i][j] = round(Inflation[i][j]/sum, 2)
    return Inflation

import math
def change(Matrix1, Matrix2):
    size = len(Matrix1)
    change = 0
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if(math.fabs(Matrix1[i][j]-Matrix2[i][j]) > change):
                change = math.fabs(Matrix1[i][j]-Matrix2[i][j])
    return change

def MCL(Matrix):
    
    Matrix = addSelfLoop(Matrix)
    print (pd.DataFrame(Matrix))
    Gamma = 2
    Transition = createTransition(Matrix)
    M1 = Transition
    print ("Transition")
    print (pd.DataFrame(M1))
    
    counter =1
    epsilon = 0.001
    change_ = float("inf")
    while (change_ > epsilon):
        print("Iterate :: ", counter,":::::::::::::::::::::::::::::")
        counter += 1
        # M_2 =  M_1 * M_1  #  expansion  
        M2 = expand(M1)
        print ("expanded\n",pd.DataFrame(M2))
        # M_1 =  Γ(M_2)     #  inflation
        M1 = inflate(M2, 2)
        print ("inflated\n",pd.DataFrame(M1))
        # change   =  difference(M_1, M_2)
        change_ = change(M1,M2)
    return M1

result = mc.run_mcl(Matrix, inflation=1.5)
clusters = mc.get_clusters(result)
print('clusters', clusters)
mc.draw_graph(Matrix, clusters, node_size=6, with_labels=False, edge_color="silver")
```

The output of cluster when inflation value=1.5.

```
clusters=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to use the modularity measure to optimize the clustering parameters to pick the best cluster inflation value for the given graph.

My code:

```
# perform clustering using different inflation values from 1.5 and 2.5
# for each clustering run, calculate the modularity
for inflation in [i / 10 for i in range(15, 26)]:
    result = mc.run_mcl(Matrix, inflation=inflation)
    clusters = mc.get_clusters(result)
    Q = mc.modularity(matrix=result, clusters=clusters)
    print("inflation:", inflation, "modularity:", Q)
```

But when I run the code I get the following error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate over a list of floats (as the exception clearly says). Do that instead:

```py
for i in range(15, 26):
   inflation = i/10
   # ... your code
```

Comment: thank you, but It not working! I used the following code: for inflation in [i/10 for i in (15, 26)]:
    inflation = i/10

Comment: his answer is correct, just replace `for inflation in [i / 10 for i in range(15, 26)]:` with `for i in (15, 26):
   inflation = i/10`

Comment: You can iterate over a list of floats, you cannot iterate over a single float.

Comment: @ oskros this solution still not working! Output: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @oskos thanks, was a copy/paste mistake. no corrected

Comment: @aam Please show your code and in what line the error happens (full error stack trace)